# php formatted html shows up in Yahoo mail but not gmail

Tags: php, html, email, gmail

I am using MAMP (LAMP stack development environment) to send emails using PHP.

The code is below:

```
$out_message = '
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>You have requested an appointment with the Smile Zone</title>
</head>

<body>
<p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><strong>Dear '.$details_name.'</strong></p>
<p style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">You have requested an appointment!</p>
<p style="padding:10px;"><strong>Please note that this appointment is currently unconfirmed</strong></p>
</body>
</html>
';

//now for the client side:
$out_to = 'john@gmail.com';
$out_subject = 'My Subject';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= "To: John <john@gmail.com> \r\n";
$headers .= 'From: The Smile Zone <noreply@smile-zone.com>' . "\r\n";

$success2 = mail($out_to, $out_subject, $out_message, $headers);
```

When I send this email and view in Apple Mail, it appears as it should, however in GMail, in the browser all I get is the raw source.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have conflicting charsets:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Change them to match.

Answer (score 0):

**Remove these tags**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>You have requested an appointment with the Smile Zone</title>
</head>

<body>
```

**Some use full links**

- [6 Easy Ways to Improve Your HTML Emails](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/6-easy-ways-to-improve-your-html-emails/)
- [20 Email Design Best Practices and Resources for Beginners](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/20-email-design-best-practices-and-resources-for-beginners/)

**Use some standard library like**

- zend_mail
- pear-mail

Comment: Also, a handy reference for formatting:  http://www.campaignmonitor.com/downloads/documents-tools/Campaign_Monitor_Guide_to_CSS_Support_in_Email_27_Aug_2009.pdf  Luckily, on this one it doesn't look like any compatibility issues apply, but it's a great resource for the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail is much less forgiving about the formatting of your emails than other web clients.  You'll need to conform to [RFC2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822).  My guess is that the [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function in PHP does not create messages that conform to that RFC for multi-part messages. (That is, messages with both a text and an HTML part.)  Per the documentation for `mail` it is better to use [`PEAR::Mail_Mime`](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime).